# (node:4677) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

im creating a discord bot in Glitch.com and i was creating a Warn command, when i finished i try to node him and it works but when I try to warn someone it not warn the user who i selected, so, i go to console log and i fund this error:

"(node:4677) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)"

I watch the async and for me it its good, but idk, can you please help me?

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const ms = require("ms");
let warns = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./warnings.json", "utf8"));

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  
  
if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("I cant warn a staff member");
  let wUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
  if(!wUser) return message.reply("Sir >:( listen plez mention someone no trollies >:(");
  if(wUser.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("hey stahp u dont have permision >:(");
  let reason = args.join(" ").slice(22);

 if(!warns[wUser.id]) warns[wUser.i
                            ] = {
   warns: 0
   
 };


warns[wUser.id].warns++;
  
  
  fs.writeFile("./warnings.json", JSON.stringify(warns), (err) => {
    
  
    if(err) console.log(err);
  });
    
  
  let warnEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setDescription("Warns")
  .setAuthor(message.author.name)
  .setColor("#ff0000")
.addField("Warned User", wUser.tag)
  .addField("Warned in", message.channel)
  .addField("Number of Warnings", warns[wUser.id].warns)
  .addField("Reason:", reason);
  
  let warnchannel = message.guild.channels.fin('name', "incidents");
  if(!warnchannel) return message.reply("Couldn't find channel, if you dont have one create one");

warnchannel.send(warnEmbed);


if(warns[wUser.id].warns == 2) {
  let muterole = message.guild.roles.fin('name', "muted");
  if(!muterole) return message.reply("You dont have a muterole!, that breaks my heart :(!");

let mutetime = "10m";
await(wUser.addRole(muterole.id));
message.channel.send('${wUser.tag} has been temporaly muted');


setTimeout(function(){
  wUser.removeRole(muterole.id)
message.channel.reply('Carlos is da best')
})



}
if(warns[wUser.id].warns == 3) {
  message.guild.member(wUser).ban(reason);
message.channel.send('${wUser.tag} has been banned.')
}
  
  
  
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, whats happening is something inside your function is throwing an error. A promise is failing to resolve. To handle promises failing you either follow with `.catch(callback)` if you are using the `.then(callback).catch(callback)` style, or you surround with

```
try{
}
catch(err){
}
```

if you're using async and await. This should help you figure out what is failing exactly

Comment: you know where i need to put that?

Comment: Id wrap the entire function in a try and catch and then log the errors and figure it bit by bit. Later you might want to wrap different parts of the code in try/catch and handle the errors.